Need a react component to scan small qr codes
I am using react-qr-barcode-scanner component in my current react js application. But it is not able to scan small ( 1cm×1cm ) qr codes printed on injection boxes. Is there any other component that can scan small qr codes. Even if it is a paid component, we want accurate scanning results
Even when I tried to zoom in, react-qr-barcode-scanner not able to scan
